# Doubt when something is some fraction less than some quantity.

Tags: word-problem

Why is $\frac{1}{4}$ less than X equals $\left(\text{X}-\frac{\text{X}}{4}\right)$ and not equals $\left(\text{X}-\frac{{1}}{4}\right)$ ?

For example: I was given the following problem to solve:

Q) One fourth less than 50% of 120 equals to ?

My solution:

50% of 120 = 60

then I did $60-\frac{1}{4}= \frac{239}{4}$

Comment: A word problem can tell you something is $x - \frac x4,$ it can tell you something is $x - \frac14,$ or it can be nonsense. It depends on the exact words used. I suggest you edit the question to show a specific word problem where you thought something should be interpreted as $x - \frac14.$

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for pointing out that I was missing the context! I have edited my post to include it.

Comment: See my comment following Ethan Bolker's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "one fourth less than" is a little bit ambiguous. It might mean "subtract $1/4$" or "find $75\%$ of".

You read it the first way.

The problem intended you to read it the second way. That is in fact the much more sensible way to read it, since the context tells you that this is a problem about percentages. Those involve multiplication and division, not addition and subtraction.

In this case there's another reason to guess that the second reading is correct. If these were real numbers that meant something (like dollars or pounds of potatoes) then the $1/4$ would be negligible in comparison to the other round numbers. Only "one fourth of the amount" would make sense.

That said, the question is very badly written. The author expects you to read his mind, since the words themselves are not clear

Comment: [1] ...The problem intended you to read it the second way. : I agree   [2] That is in fact the much more sensible way to read it : Oh really? : I (also) interpreted "...one fourth less than ..." as the OP did.  The problem composer could have easily instead said "...75% of the following : 50 % of ..." or "...(3/4) **of** 50 % of ...".  Assuming that you are right about the problem composer's intent, this is simply a very poorly worded problem.

Comment: I suspect it is mainly the mathematically-inclined who will read it as $X-\frac14.$  While I would prefer to read it the same way as @user2661923 , I'm used to the idiomatic/intended interpretation being $X-\frac14 X.$ Yes, the exercise is poorly-worded.

Comment: @user2661923 See my edit.

Comment: @RyanG Perhaps the mathematically inclined might read it literally as $X - 1/4$. An applied mathematician would sense the implicit units and read it as the writer intended. But we agree that the question is terribly worded - see my edit.

Comment: @EthanBolker I agree about the engineering-inclined. In any case, all of us are just trying to second-guess the author.

Comment: I agree with all the above. The actual wording of this problem is very close to my third case (namely, nonsense), though I suppose I should have added a fourth possibility where the statement is ambiguous. In terms of what makes sense to ask as a word problem, however, I would guess $X - \frac X4$ if this were my homework or an exam question. And I would hope to advance later to a math class where the problems are better worded.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x}{4} &\lt x-\dfrac{x}{4}\Large{?}\\ \\
x-\dfrac{x}{4}
&=\dfrac{4x-x}{4}=\frac{3x}{4}\\ \\
\dfrac{x}{4} &\lt \frac{3x}{4}\\ \\
\therefore\space \dfrac{x}{4} &\lt x-\dfrac{x}{4}
\end{align*}